# Is it better practice to cast or to use overloaded methods?

Tags: java, casting, operator-overloading

**UPDATE** This question is less concerned with the most efficient way to improve upon the following example code, as it is about the underlying reasons of why casting is (or is not) preferred to using overloaded methods (and in what situations). As such, answers that fall within the above scope will be the greatest help. Thanks.

I have a general 'best practices' question regarding the usage of overloaded methods versus casting, and would like to know which one is considered 'better' and why.

Say, for example, I have two different kinds of objects, such as Animal-Object and a Computer-Object, that I wish to add to a primitive array (not an ArrayList) via two methods that are exactly the same in every respect other than their type. In such a situation, is it considered better to create two separate methods with the same name (one for each type) in an overloaded-method approach, or would it be wiser to create a single method composed of 'Object' objects and then cast into the desired type later?

OPTION ONE (untested code)

```
public Animal[] updateArray(Animal name, Animal[] animalArray){
    Animal[] updatedArray = null;

    if(animalArray==null){
        updatedArray = new String[1];
        updatedArray[0] = name; 
    }else{
        updatedArray = new Animal[animalArray.length +1];
        for(int i = 0; i<animalArray.length;i++){
            updatedArray[i] = animalArray[i];
        }
        updatedArray[updatedArray.length-1] = name;
    }
    return updatedArray;
}
```

AND...

```
public Computer[] updateArray(Computer name, Computer[] computerArray){
        Computer[] updatedArray = null;

        if(computerArray==null){
            updatedArray = new String[1];
            updatedArray[0] = name; 
        }else{
            updatedArray = new Computer[computerArray.length +1];
            for(int i = 0; i<computerArray.length;i++){
                updatedArray[i] = computerArray[i];
            }
            updatedArray[updatedArray.length-1] = name;
        }
        return updatedArray;
}
```

OPTIONS TWO: USE A MORE GENERIC WAY OF DOING THINGS AND CAST INTO THE PROPER TYPE INSTEAD...
(untested code)

```
public Object[] updateArray(Object name, Object[] computerArray){
        Object[] updatedArray = null;

        if(computerArray==null){
            updatedArray = new String[1];
            updatedArray[0] = name; 
        }else{
            updatedArray = new Computer[computerArray.length +1];
            for(int i = 0; i<computerArray.length;i++){
                updatedArray[i] = computerArray[i];
            }
            updatedArray[updatedArray.length-1] = name;
        }
        return updatedArray;
}
```

and used in some method like...

```
Animal[] animalArray = (Animal[]) updateArray(name, array); 
Computer[] computerArray = (Computer[]) updateArray(name, array);
```

In short, which way of doing things is better and for what reasons--and if both have costs and benefits worth knowing, then please state those reasons as well. 
Thank you

Comment: No, I actually mean overloading. For example, http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use a generic method:

```
static<T> T[] updateArray(T t, T[] ary) {
    T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(ary, ary.length+1);
    result[ary.length] = t;
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately, arrays and generics don't mix well and there are various pitfalls.  For example, checking the array for null and creating a new array as you do in your code becomes hairy.  This is why we have `ArrayList` -- the batman of array handling.  It gets its hands dirty so we don't have to.

Comment: Misha, I greatly appreciate your advice on the specific example above, however, the larger goal of my question was understanding when and why casting is preferred to using overloaded methods, do you have any advice on this? Also doesn't the ArrayList, not being a primitive data-type and all, pretty much do the exact same thing as above? Why would that be considered 'hairy' I guess is what I am asking. Thanks